# Centring Table Rows Individually/Independently

Tags: tables, formatting

Relative newbie to Latex here who would appreciate as much help with table formatting as possible.

More specifically, in the table below I would like to ensure that the row with the word `loadings' in centred.

As it stands, I have played around with various settings of P{} to provide the illusion of `loadings' being centred, but I wondered if there was an argument to ensure that I can control this row more accurately?

All help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\lstset{   breaklines=true }
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{table}[H]
        \scriptsize
        \centering
        \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
        \caption{Principal Components Analysis:}
        \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} P{2.5cm}  P{1.4cm} P{2.7cm} P{1.4cm} P{1.4cm}}  
        \midrule
        \midrule
            & PC1  & PC2 & PC3 & PC4  \\ 
            \midrule
            \midrule
            Eigenvalues & 2.5819 & 0.9778 & 0.7818 & 0.4241 \\  
            \midrule
            \midrule 
            & &  Loadings & &  \\
            \midrule 
            \midrule 
            Mobility  & 0.7978  &-0.3522  &-0.0176 &  0.5000 \\
            Selfcare &   0.8918 &  -0.2196 & -0.0903 & -0.1244 \\
            Activities & 0.8643 & -0.1499 &   0.0044 &  -0.3981 \\ 
            Pain &        0.4628 &   0.6131 &   0.6776 &   0.0599 \\
            Anxiety &     0.4376 &  0.6117 & -0.6000 &   0.0563 \\
        
            \midrule
            \midrule
            
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at siunitx. You're table will look much nicer if you properly align the numbers instead of centering them

Comment: Please post a *complete* minimal code. At the very least the `booktabs` package is needed, and I have no idea where a `P` column might be defined. This being said, I think you just need a `\multicolumn` instead of guessing.

Comment: Thanks @campa. I'll look at the \multicolumn argument. @@samcarter. I appreciate your feedback. Thank you. I looked. But it is another hurdle atm for a learner. I'll stick with the multicolumn stuff.

Comment: While it's (of course!) ok to upvote helpful answers immedately, site guidelines strongly discourage "accepting" the first answer that comes along right away. Instead, users are encouraged several hours, and maybe even a day or two, before "accepting" any given answer. That way, you don't discourage others from posting additional, and potentially even better, answers.

Comment: @Mico. Very good point. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Since you load `tabularray` package, I would use it for writing this table. Beside to write word  "Loadings" into multi column cell, I would use `siunitx` columns for aligning numbers at decimal points:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Principal Components Analysis:}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {X[c] *{4}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.4}]}},
             row{1}  = {guard}
             }
    \toprule
            & PC1       & PC2       & PC3       & PC4       \\
    \midrule
Eigenvalues & 2.5819    &  0.9778   &  0.7818   &  0.4241   \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=5]{guard, c}    Loadings 
            &           &           &           &           \\
    \midrule
Mobility    & 0.7978    & -0.3522   & -0.0176   &  0.5000   \\
Selfcare    & 0.8918    & -0.2196   & -0.0903   & -0.1244   \\
Activities  & 0.8643    & -0.1499   &  0.0044   & -0.3981   \\
Pain        & 0.4628    &  0.6131   &  0.6776   &  0.0599   \\
Anxiety     & 0.4376    &  0.6117   & -0.6000   &  0.0563   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You may more liked that word "Loadings" will be across the four data columns, as suggested @Mico in his comment bellow. In this case the row:

```
\SetCell[c=5]{guard, c}    Loadings 
            &           &           &           &           \\
```

should be replace with:

```
            &   \SetCell[c=4]{guard, c}    Loadings 
                        &           &           &           \\
```

By this change the table looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: @Mico, you may be right. From question I figured out that word  "Loadings" should bein the middle of row. I will add addendum with suggested solution.

Comment: Hi @Zarko. Very helpful. Thank you for your time today. You're right. It was across five. And thank you for the additional detail for controlling 4 or 5.

Comment: @EB3112, sorry, I can't figured out what is your problem. If you like to reduce font size used in `table` just add `\scriptsize` after `\begin{table}[htb]` (as you have in your MWE (Minimal Working Example).  However, I wonder, why you should change font size used in table. It has sufficient space for normal font size (12pt). Or your document has two columns (this is not evident from your question}. Please elaborate your question and comment!

Comment: Hi @Zarko. Thanks. Got it working. It was really just a preference for smaller text nested within the table. Simply a visual preference so that tables are differentiated from the main body in my draft.

Comment: @EB3112, it is up to you. But using `\scriptsize` font size table will looks ugly (to my opinion) .

Answer (score 4):

I can see no reason for employing a `tabular*` environment (with a target width of `\textwidth`) for the table at hand, for using `\scriptsize` for the contents of the table, or for using `\footnotesize` for the caption. I would further suggest centering the word "Loadings" across the four data columns, not across all five columns.

In addition, please don't employ `\midrule` willy-nilly, and certainly don't double up on them. Instead, do learn to use the user macros `toprule`, `\bottomrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\addlinespace` where appropriate. By the way, the author of the `booktabs` package has this to say about double rules, at the top of section 2 of the package's user guide: "Never use double rules." Sage advice! Do take it to heart.

Finally, please make an effort to align the numbers in the four data columns on the decimal markers; in the code below, this is done with the help of the `S` column type provided by the `siunitx` package.

The horizontal line at the top of the following screenshot is drawn merely to illustrate the width of the text block. Notice that the width of the `tabular` environment is not much more than just one half of `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% this preamble is deliberately kept minimal
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block
\begin{table}[ht]
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} % default is 1\baselineskip

\centering
\caption{Principal Components Analysis}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l T{1.4} *{3}{T{-1.4}} @{}}  
\toprule % not "\midrule \midrule"
& {PC1} & {PC2} & {PC3} & {PC4} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-5} % not "\midrule \midrule"
Eigenvalues & 2.5819 & 0.9778 & 0.7818 & 0.4241 \\  
\addlinespace  % not "\midrule \midrule"
& \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Loadings} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}  % not "\midrule \midrule"
Mobility  & 0.7978 & -0.3522 & -0.0176 &  0.5000 \\
Selfcare  & 0.8918 & -0.2196 & -0.0903 & -0.1244 \\
Activities& 0.8643 & -0.1499 &  0.0044 & -0.3981 \\ 
Pain      & 0.4628 &  0.6131 &  0.6776 &  0.0599 \\
Anxiety   & 0.4376 &  0.6117 & -0.6000 &  0.0563 \\
\bottomrule  % not "\midrule \midrule"
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Mico, thanks for your time and comments. Very useful to see all the different approaches. I agree with you that my midrule stuff is poorly conceived and illadvised. When I first wrote the table (6-7 months ago), this was my first time on Latex. So it was a brute force method I used in draft format. Of course, I'm here to refine that. So thanks for pointers, comments, and answer :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd avoid double rules. Also, it doesn't seem necessary to reduce the size, *unless* you're in two-column format. Thus I'll assume it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

% choose a reduced size
%\small
\footnotesize

% local settings
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\?}{\hphantom{$-$}}

\caption{Principal Components Analysis}

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=-1.4]
  S[table-format=-1.4]
  S[table-format=-1.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& {PC1}  & {\?PC2} & {\?PC3} & {\?PC4}  \\ 
\midrule
Eigenvalues & 2.5819 & 0.9778 & 0.7818 & 0.4241 \\  
\midrule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Loadings} \\
\cmidrule{2-5} 
Mobility   & 0.7978 & -0.3522 & -0.0176 &  0.5000 \\
Selfcare   & 0.8918 & -0.2196 & -0.0903 & -0.1244 \\
Activities & 0.8643 & -0.1499 &  0.0044 & -0.3981 \\ 
Pain       & 0.4628 &  0.6131 &  0.6776 &  0.0599 \\
Anxiety    & 0.4376 &  0.6117 & -0.6000 &  0.0563 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I did a small cheat: since the eigenvalues row follows immediately the headers and there's no minus sign in them, the headers would appear misaligned, so I add the space of the minus sign to compensate.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `\?` macro to fine-tune horizontal placement of cell contents.

Comment: Hi @egreg. Thank you. Another great tip. Thanks for your time and answer :)